# Segmentation fault from lfind?

Tags: c

I'm getting a segmentation fault on the lfind call with this code. CVector is a struct with an array called elems. I know the CVectorCreate and CVectorAppend functions work. The first block is the test code, which is provided as part of the class and can't be changed, and the second is the function call that I wrote. Can someone help me identify my issue? Thanks!

```
 char *jumbled = "xatmpdvyhglzjrknicoqsbuewf";
 CVector *cv = CVectorCreate(sizeof(char), 4, NULL);
 for (int i = 0; i < strlen(jumbled); i++)
    CVectorAppend(cv, &jumbled[i]);                      
 printf("\nDoing linear searches on unsorted cvector.\n");
 char ch = '*';
 Verify(0, CVectorSearch(cv, &jumbled[0], CmpCharElem, 0, false), "Linear search"); 




int CVectorSearch(const CVector *cv, const void *key, CVectorCmpElemFn cmpfn, int startIndex, bool isSorted)
{
  assert(startIndex >= 0 && startIndex <= cv->logicalLength);
  void *found = NULL;
  if (isSorted == true) {
    found = bsearch(key, (char *)(cv->elems) + (startIndex * cv->elemSize),
            cv->logicalLength, cv->elemSize, cmpfn);
  } else {
     found = lfind(key, (char *)(cv->elems) + (startIndex * cv->elemSize), cv->logicalLength, cv->elemSize, cmpfn);
  }
```

Comment: `&jumbled[0]` - Just pass in `jumbled`, it is already a pointer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike `bsearch`, the third argument to `lfind` is a pointer.

```
 size_t nmemb = cv->logicalLength;
 found = lfind(key, (char *)(cv->elems) + (startIndex * cv->elemSize),
               &nmemb, cv->elemSize, cmpfn);
```

Comment: That worked as far as removing the segfault, thanks a lot. Another issue if you don't mind with the same call: elems is allocated to be an array of length 32 at this point, but there are 26 filled elements. Lfind seems to automatically try to compare the 6 uninitialized values as part of its search as well. How can I stop it from doing this?

Comment: @JasonBlock: You shouldn't lie to `lfind` about how many elements are in the array. If you know you will always have extra, you can write into the 27-th place the key you wish to find, so that `lfind` will find it, even if it is not in the first 26.